# Is the buffer in this power supply circuit required?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier

In the circuit below, the potentiometer is used to adjust VCOMMON to the specified (usually around -1.25 V) output.

VCOMMON is supplied to an e-ink display, and the datasheet says that the typical current draw is 0.2mA.

My understanding is that the LM358 acts as a non-inverting buffer. Is this really needed? Can't the potentiometer be directly connected VCOMMON?

Or is this a safety feature for impedance matching?

[image: Non inverting buffer for power supply]

Comment: How much current is going to be sourced or sunk from VCOMMON?

Comment: It's less than 1 mA. I'll update the question.

Comment: What's 1 mA times 100 kohms?

Comment: You might be able to do what you're suggesting if the voltage divider used lower-valued resistors.  The tradeoff is more wasted current through the resistors.

Comment: And what is the required voltage tolerance? What is the load variability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no safety concern, nor "impedance matching" (since we don't know any load characteristics). If you use just a 100k trimpot, the current carrying capability of this "power supply" will be about 20 uA (micro Amperes). The LM358 buffer allows this power supply to supply 20-30mA of current at stable -1.25V voltage level. Not much per power supply standards, but still quite more than 20uA.

ADDITION: If it is required only 0.2mA and cost is of concern, the most economical solution could be to use "parametric regulator" using a 1.7-1.8V Zener diode and 30k resistor, with a ~5k trimpot to adjust the voltage to -1.25V, assuming 15-20% of voltage tolerance and not much of load variability.

Answer (score 2):

It depends entirely on what is connected to VCOMMON. I'll take a wild stab and guess it might possibly go to an LM317, in which case the minimum load is about 5mA (typically a 240 ohm resistor) so that amount of current would greatly affect the voltage from your 100K pot. The voltage follower buffers the voltage so it is relatively stable (well, unless it oscillates merrily because of that 100n, or unless the -15V supply changes).

Edit: with 0.2mA load the output voltage typically will change by almost 5V typically if set to -1.25V, and much more if set higher.

If you reduced the pot and resistor to 100 ohms/200 ohms it would probably work fine without the op-amp except it would waste a lot of power- 0.25W in the pot and 0.5W in the resistor,

Comment: I've updated the question. VCOMMON goes to a display which draws 0.2 mA typically.

Comment: The typical draw is 0.2 mA. More important is what is the maximum draw?

Comment: Unfortunately the maximum is not mentioned in the data sheet.